# Null error when binding piped argument to function paramater

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm trying to make a Powershell function that takes in a piped string (from ExpandProperty).

for some reason I keep getting a null error (attached below),
but if I run the code without the last piped command it works fine. I tried wrapping the Get-ChildItem pipeline in an array (@) too, but that didn't help.

---

#### error code

```
Get-FolderSize : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'folderpath' because it is null.
At line:31 char:106
+ ... ainer } |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Get-FolderSize $_
+                                                                        ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-FolderSize], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Get-FolderSize
```

---

#### code

```
$dirpath = "C:\SomeFolder"

Function Get-FolderSize {
    # allows cmd options 
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        $folderpath = $(Throw "no folder name specified")
    )
    if ($foldepath -eq $null){
        return 0 
    }
    $folderpath = Convert-Path {$folderpath}

    $size = 0

    # calculate folder size and recurse as needed
    Foreach ($file in $(ls $folderpath -recurse)){
     If (-not ($file.psiscontainer)) {
        $size += $file.length
        }
    }

    # return the value and go back to caller
    return $size
}
$Files = @(gci $dirpath -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName) 
if ($Files.length -eq 0) {
  write-host "   no files to delete." 
} else {
  $Files
}
```

Comment: In order for your function to receive objects from the pipeline at least one of your parameters must be set to allow values from pipeline.  You will also need a Process {} block.  Give this a read - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/incorporating-pipelined-input-into-powershell-functions/

Comment: As it wasn't specifically mentioned in the existing answer, you don't need to use `PSIsContainer`, i.e. `ls $folderpath -file -recurse` and `gci $dirpath -File -Recurse`, unless your script needs to run on a PowerShell version before v3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning, there are a few things I can point out. Indeed if you use advanced parameters and `[cmdletbinding()]` as you have here you need `Begin{}`, `Process{}` & `End{}` blocks.  The process block will be run once for every object passed down the pipeline.

There are also a number of things you can do a lot easier in PowerShell:

```
Function Get-FolderSize {

    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param ( 
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline )]
        [String[]]$FolderPath
    ) # End Param Block
    
    Begin{}

    Process
    {
        [UInt64](Get-ChildItem $FolderPath -Recurse -File |
        Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
    } # End Process Block
    
    End{}
} # End Function Get-FolderSize
```

- You don't really need to throw an error for the FolderPath parameter. You've already made it mandatory. If it isn't specified, the function will prompt for it.
- Add `ValueFromPipeline` parameter attribute, `Begin{}`, `Process{}` & `End{}` blocks to enable pipeline input.
- I'm not sure what `Convert-Path` was doing there, doesn't look necessary.
- Use the `-File` switch parameter with `Get-ChildItem` to recursively list all the files without having to perform logic on `.PSIsContainer`.
- Use `Measure-Object` to sum the file sizes for you emit its sum property.  Notice you don't need to assign that to a variable, or use the return statement. Anything emitted from the function will be returned to the caller.

Note: I also returned the value casted to a `[UInt64]` numeric type.  This helps in flipping null returns to zero without disallowing very large numbers.

I also casted the `-FolderPath` parameter as a string array (`[string[]]`).  I'm not sure if your intent is really to allow multiple objects down the pipe, but if you do it will return a sum for each path you give it.  At any rate this is how I would start a function like this.

I'm not sure what you were doing with the rest of the code, I don't see where you were calling the function.  However, I get the feeling you wanted to list the folders with their sizes.  With the above function in hand, that might look something like:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Directory | 
Select-Object *,@{Name = 'FolderSize'; Expression = { Get-FolderSize $_.FullName }} | 
Format-Table FullName,FolderSize -Wrap
```

There's obviously a lot more to writing advanced functions.  There is no shortage of reading material, just google it...